# TextBox в другом потоке, чем сама программа

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, com-port

Белеберда, данные получает отлично, и я их вижу через консоль,
а выводить в текстбокс отказывается.

```
MainWindow()
{
    var port = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM2");
    port.DataReceived += (port, e)=>{ AddText(port.ReadExisting().ToString()); };
}

void AddText(string message)
{
    textbox.AppendText(message);//TextBox  --- ERRRRRROR
    // Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток.
}
```

P.S.
WPF, FW 4 Client, VisualStudio 2013 Pro Upd4. W8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(()=> textbox.AppendText(message));
```

Answer (score 4):

MSDN:

Событие DataReceived генерируется в дополнительном потоке при поступлении данных из объекта SerialPort. Поскольку это событие наступает в дополнительном потоке, а не в основном, попытка изменить некоторые элементы в основном потоке (например, элементы интерфейса пользователя) может вызвать исключение потоковой обработки. Если необходимо изменить элементы в основной форме Form или в Control, выполните обратный запрос изменения с помощью метода Invoke, который выполнит требуемые действия в соответствующем потоке.

Answer (score 1):

```
MainWindow()
{
    var port = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM2");
    port.DataReceived += (port, e)=>{

    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new Action(() => AddText(port.ReadExisting().ToString())));
    }
    else AddText(port.ReadExisting().ToString());
    };
}
```